# Appending value to an array that is in a sub-collection in mongodb with ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document structure as follows

```
{
   _id: 32131

   names:
   {
      current : {value : 1, name: a} 
      prev : [{value : 2, name: b}, {value : 3, name: c} , {value : 4, name: d} ]
   }


}
```

When I get a new record that I need to insert in the `names` field, I want to get the record in the `current` field and push it to the prev array. Then I want to insert the new record into the `current` field. The new record will always have a unique `value`.

For example, if I get a new record as `{value: 5, name : e}`, I want the above document to look like the following

```
   {
       _id: 32131
       names:
       {
          current : {value : 5, name: e} 
          prev : [{value : 2, name: b}, {value : 3, name: c} , {value : 4, name: d}, {value : 1, name: a}]
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are basically trying to do here is not un-reasonable, but there is of course a distinct problem. The problem is that at present there is no way for MongoDB to refer to the exsiting values present in other fields and use them as part of an update.

So a pseudo-code of what you want in basic JavaScript shell form would be:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 32131 },
    { 
        "$set": { "names.current": { "value": 5, "name": "e" } },
        "$push": { "names.prev": { 
            "value": this.names.current.value, 
            "name": this.names.current.name
        }}
    }
)
```

But of course that does not exist and does not work.

What I would suggest is to "turn the problem on it's head", and basically *also* store the current value in the array:

```js
{
   "_id": 32131,
   "names": {
      "current" : { "value": 1, "name": "a" } 
      "revisions": [
          { "value": 2, "name": "b" }, 
          { "value": 3, "name": "c" }, 
          { "value": 4, "name": "d" },
          { "value": 1, "name": "a" } 
      ]
   }
}
```

So with that "current" value already present in the array then changing the data and also adding the "current" is very simple:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 32131 },
    { 
        "$set": { "names.current": { "value": 5, "name": "e" } },
        "$push": { "names.revisions": { 
            "value": 5,
            "name": "e"
        }}
    }
)
```

You can always work at "filtering" the "current" value from the array when you query in some form of logic on the client or server.

But that is what I see as your best approach, otherwise you will need to "read" the data to know that is there before you "write". And that will cause concurrency problems.